# Узнать как выглядит сайт на разных разрешениях экрана

Tags: браузер, веб-служба

Какие есть полезные инструменты, сервисы? Помимо режима разработчика

Comment: Для адаптивной верстки, удобно использовать масштабирование ctrl+колесо. При увеличении масштаба разрешение экрана как будто уменьшается, а при уменьшении масштаба - увеличивается.

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуй лучший сервис для проверки кроссбраузерности это [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/).

Помимо проверки как будет отображаться на устройствах с разными экранами вы сразу проверите как ваш сайт будет работать в iOS разных версий (это на самом деле важно).

Имеет достаточно большое кол-во устройств и позволит полноценно без установки разного софта и кучи закладок всё вроверить.

Ну и классический приём "тянуть" браузер как вам нужно.